# Traefik: Matching a IP and PORT with no HOST name, using IngressRoute

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I need to map over a pure static IP with a specific port, it has no hostname attached to. The static IP is exactly the same as what a domain points to, but I need only the IP. The Entrypoint is on a specific port - actually port 9735.

I have this working but I am unsure if I am doing it correct. For testing purposes I added a simple whoami website on there.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: whoami

spec:
  entryPoints:
    - lnd1
  routes:
    - match: Path(`/`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: whoami
          port: 80
```

So if I go to my browser and add

```
http://88.x.x.x:9735
```

Then it works. if I put

```
http://88.x.x.x:9735/somepath
```

It does not. Is it possible to use a wildcard with

```
    - match: Path(`/`)
```

Or maybe this is completely the wrong direction. Although it does work, maybe its not the right approach..

All I need to do is capture all traffic on a specific port (not 80 or 443) and forward it to a service.

I know the entrypoints are setup correctly as they are working, for reference, I am using this

```
ports:
  lnd1:
    port: 9735
    expose: true
    exposedPort: 9735
    # The port protocol (TCP/UDP)
    protocol: TCP
```

My doubt is weather I should be using a Match (can you exclude it :-) ? ) - and what kind of match I should be using.

Any ideas

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In traefik docs I have found that beside the `Path()` rule, there is also `PathPrefix()` which is most probably what you want to use.

Here is what [the docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/) says:

> Path Vs PathPrefix
>
> Use Path if your service listens on the exact path only. For instance,
> Path: /products would match /products but not /products/shoes.
>
> Use a *Prefix* matcher if your service listens on a particular base
> path but also serves requests on sub-paths. For instance, PathPrefix:
> /products would match /products but also /products/shoes and
> /products/shirts. Since the path is forwarded as-is, your service is
> expected to listen on /products.

So your ingress route would look like following:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: whoami
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - lnd1
  routes:
    - match: PathPrefix(`/`)    # <-------------
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: whoami
          port: 80
```